# Add rows to table in Google Docs

Tags: google-docs

Any way to add a row to a table in Google Docs? I've tried to click everything, but I find no button to add a row;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Highlight a cell (long press) in Google Docs and you would see at bottom option to "add row below" ; slide menu to reveal "add above" (not in pic)

[image]